# Include Special Characters in XML parsing

Tags: xml, nsxmlparser

I am trying to do XML parsing. The XML contains url of certain images. Now the url contains special characters like çú and ña. Now if try using encoding and replace special characters I will be unable to get image from url because I changed it and if I don't NSXML parser will not parse it.
So is their any way that I can include the special characters in xml parsing.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Include the xml to the question

Comment: Not related to Xcode.

Comment: It is related to XCode. Sorry I forgot to tag it.

Comment: @SurbhitThanvi No, your question have *nothing* to do with xcode. Please read the description for the xcode tag.